# Recommendations for an external email marketing service

Tags: email, spam

First off, let me say that the small number of emails we send out are not spam. We include removal links and the emails are generally centered around free webinars that our marketing department hosts.

The problem I've had in the past is being put on an RBL list. How it happened previously was a few hotmail recipients must have marked the email as spam. After Microsoft marks you as a spammer the RBL's are soon to follow. It has only happened that one time but once was most certainly enough. So, I'm looking for recommendations for an external email marketing service. Things to take in to consideration are cost, features/reports, and reputation. [iContact](http://www.icontact.com/) would be an example, although I have never used that service personally.

Is this solution one that many of you have tried? It's just that I don't want any disruption to company emails, ever. These marketing emails are just too risky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three that I have had heard good things about:

- [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/)
- [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp)
- [Emma](http://www.myemma.com/)

I would also question where you are getting your email addresses from. If you are mailing enough "Marketing" emails to Hotmail and people are clicking that "spam" button, it means that they don't want your emails. Free webinars, even though you consider them a "service" are still marketing and your email lists must be confirmed opt in to reduce the amount of receivers who click on that spam button. Otherwise, no matter what service you are using, it will eventually get in RBLs or you will be kicked off of the service.

Also, just because Hotmail puts you on their blacklists, doesn't mean that the other ones "copy" them. They each have their own ways of adding onto their lists, but most of them have spam-traps and if you send even a single message to one of those email addresses, you will be added to their blacklist.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) now for about 2 years.  I can attest to their outstanding customer service, extremely reasonable pricing AND they will kick your ass if you spam people.

They do everything they can to prevent you from getting blacklisted.  They offer help with subject lines, proof of opt-in, etc.

Standard reporting is pretty basic.  However, they do have a package that you can upgrade to (I think it's $40) that will get you much better reporting.  They also integrate with Twitter and Google Analytics.

I truly cannot say enough good things about them.

Comment: Ensure that we do not spam is absolutly fantastic. I just did the web tour and their product looks great. I am curious to see how other suggestions match up.

Comment: They also offer a reasonable free version.